# Nginx returns "No input file specified" when serving PHP script

Tags: php, windows, nginx, iis, fastcgi

I'm brand new to PHP.  See my Nginx configuration below to see how I can avoid getting the error `No input file specified` in my browser when I go to url:  http://mywebsite.com/php/gateway.php?xxxxxxxx

**nginx.conf:**

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl http2; 
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
        ssl_certificate     ./ssl/nginx.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key ./ssl/nginx.key;
        server_name_in_redirect off;
        log_not_found off;
        server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        root   /inetpub/wwwroot;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9123;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

I have also tried: changing:

```
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

to

```
fastcgi_param  /php/gateway.php $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

No matter what I try, I keep getting the `No input file specified` response.

Comment: I wonder where did you get that `fastcgi_param  /php/gateway.php $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;` line? It should be `fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;`.

Comment: Thanks.  That was my bright idea.  Its because even using SCRIPT_FILENAME didn't work.

Comment: You brightest idea is to use `root` directive inside the `location / { ... }` block instead of `server` context. This means the `location \.php$ { ... }` block uses default nginx root directory (which is usually `/path/to/nginx/executable/html`).

Comment: @IvanShatsky you helped me once again!  Thanks, buddy!